# Failed to load open-nfc addon in android platform

Tags: android, nfc, open-nfc

This is the first time, I am working on`open-nfc`. As per official [documentation](http://open-nfc.org/wp/editions/android/) I created new `avd` with Open NFC edition as target.

Now as per 5th step, I switch to `platform-tools` and then ran `adb devices`. it's showing

```
 List of devices attached
 emulator-5554 device
```

after ran next command `adb pull /data/connection_center_access`, It's throwing `remote object '/data/connection_center_access' does not exist`.

This where, I stuck.

Regarding this, I seen [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnS8jbk6oA0), they are not suggesting to modify any thing, so without doing 5th step, directly I jump to 7th step, When I try to open `Connection Center` It's throwing `An error occured while loading the archive`.

I think, it's because of 5th step problem.

I trying to figure it out from last 1 day,can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent a couple of hours trying to make OpenNFC Work, as I needed it too. I noticed a few things, hope those can help you:

1 - Check your Android SDK Manager; the OpenNFC package miss a required file, source.properties. You have to create it, but if you don't fill it with the right values it's useless. After a bit of trying, I've found that this works correctly:

```
Addon.NameDisplay=addon-2013-02-28_android-4.2.1_r1_OpenNFC_4.5.2  
Addon.NameId=OpenNFC_4.5.2  
Addon.VendorId=OpenNFC
Addon.VendorDisplay=OpenNFC
AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=17
Archive.Os=ANY
Archive.Arch=ANY
Pkg.Revision=1
```

2 - Check that your AVD it's really targetting the OpenNFC image. Documentation says "chose the Target corresponding to the Open NFC edition", but that not means to create an AVD targeting the same api level as the NFC package (exactly what I did in the first place), instead you should choose as target the matching Addon.NameDisplay that you put in the source.properties.

File data/connection_center_access is a specific and custom file that reside only on OpenNFC custom image; if adb pull cannot find it, you are running a wrong image, not OpenNFC one.

3 - If you are running on a windows system and have UAC set, remember to launch Connection Center in administrative mode (right click->etc. etc.); documentation totally forget to say that.