# Android emulated devices communicating via NFC

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, nfc, emulation

I have an Android app for API 25-34 whose main functionality is based on communication between 2 Android devices via NFC.

I have only a single physical device available to me but I, obviously, need 2 of them to test and debug the app.

I would like to know if there is a way to establish such communication between 2 emulated devices or between one physical connected with USB and one emulated, using Android Studio emulation environment or some other tool.

I also would like to know if or how I could run automated tests for the NFC communication scenarios between these emulated Android devices.

I would be thankful for any help or clues on how to accomplish these goals.

Comment: Related: [NFC tag emulation for Android virtual device (AVD)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49293691/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang thank you for the input, although the answer dates back to 2018. It's been 5 years since, and there may be some new solutions. Although I haven't found any yet.